# Strange issue with Jquery Qtip,tooltip not working correctly after first mouseover

Tags: php, jquery, live, qtip

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?  The qtip works ok on mouseover the first time, but the second time it shows 2 tooltips, one with what ever I have in the title attribute and another one on top of that one that's empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tooltip").bind('mouseover', function() {  
    $(this).qtip({
      overwrite: false,                 
      show: {
         ready: true
      }
    });  
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overwrite` to `true`

> Determines if, when the .qtip() method is called on an element with a
>   qTip already present, the new one overrides (i.e. destroys) the old
>   one. By default this is true.

ie if set to false, a new qtip is created each `mouseover`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bind mouseover. qtip does that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tooltip').qtip({
    overwrite: true,                 
    show: {
      ready: true
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:
You didn't tell anything about ajax. So this should work([jsFiddle case](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/QJKSP/));

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tooltip").bind('mouseover', function() {  
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('qtip') == null) {
      $this.qtip({
        overwrite: true,                 
        show: {
          ready: true
        }
      });  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Without binding it, the plugin breaks when using Ajax.

Comment: Updated my answer. But this is not a good way to do it. If I were you, I set a variable with default options for qtip and after ajax calls call qtip on newly created items with previously saved qtip options.